# Python 3 Online Interpreter / Shell

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, interpreter

Is there an online interpreter like http://codepad.org/ or http://www.trypython.org/ which uses Python 3?

**Answer**

Since the question is closed, I give another answer here.

[Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) offers online REPLs for many languages, including Python 2.x and 3.x, C++ and Java.

Comment: 29 people voted this question up, 7 added it to their favourites. So is this question really "not constructive"? I think tools, even the little ones, are very important for software development.

Comment: Voting to leave closed. Tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic because they tend to gather spam answers.

Comment: Then remove the spam answers. Not the question.

Comment: Please reopen it. The question is very useful, and a lot of new stuff appeared after closure that it woul dbe good to track here. This question is the 3rd result in google for "Python 3 online", i guess a lot of people could benefit from updated answers.

Comment: [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3) is breaking the internet with [Python 3.6.1](https://repl.it/languages/python3) at the moment. Supports latest of all version listed here.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Ideone](http://ideone.com) supports Python 2.6 and Python 3

Comment: it doesn't know matplotlib library. I wish I could use it like the Python on my desktop.

Comment: @Kamran I can see such wishes at [Ideone FB proile](http://www.facebook.com/ideone) (some of them succesfully implemented).

Comment: @kami: If you want Python like Python on your desktop, you need to use Python on your desktop.

Comment: @kami: grab an inexpensive VPS like DigitalOcean and fire an IPython notebook with authentication listening in all IPs.

Comment: http://repl.it/languages/Python3 supports python 3

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across Python 3 interpreter at [CompileOnline](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python3_online.php).

Comment: Oops..didn't check. Appspot uses Python 2.5.2. My bad...

Comment: This one, http://pyeval.appspot.com/index.html, has a friendlier interface

Comment: Either interfaces don't support Python 3.