# How can I run online python code that requires a set of modules?

Tags: python

How can I run online python code that owns/requires a set of modules? (e.g. numpy, matplotlib) Answers/suggestions to questions [2737539](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737539/python-3-online-interpreter-shell) and [3356390](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356390/is-there-an-online-interpreter-for-python-3) about interpreters in python 3, are not useful because those compilers don't work properly in this case.

Comment: So what i get out of your question, you want to create an online intepreter to run a python script with a set of modules?

Comment: I'm just asking if that online compiler does exist, if the answer is positive, please tell me where can I found it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one that supports multiple modules, i checked `numpy, scipy, psutil, matplotlib, etc` and all of them are supported. Check out pythonanyware compiler, a sample console is [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/), however you can signup for accounts [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/pricing/), i believe there is a free version. I remember i used that that online compiler last year and it worked quite well, but for a free account it has certain limits. It also has a bash console, which allows you to run the python files.

Comment: Great, it is what I's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this as sandbox, it support numpy as well: http://ideone.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the best editors I found on internet , which has not only your requirements but more than that.
Here is the link - [Replit](https://replit.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This works reasonably well for me.You can [check it](https://onecompiler.com/python/) out
https://onecompiler.com/python